# Dynamic binding to a "Path" of the resource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dynamicresource

First the code what I was starting from:

```
<ribbon:RibbonMenuButton IsEnabled="{Binding ForegroundIsConfigurable}"
          SmallImageSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource imageSource},
                             Path=Source,
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=OnPropertyChanged}">
```

While this binding is compiling and running fine the reason I am not satisfied is that `imageSource` changes during runtime.

> [StaticResource Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx): Provides a value for any XAML property attribute by looking up a reference to an already defined resource. Lookup behavior for that resource is analogous to load-time lookup, which will look for resources that were previously loaded from the markup of the current XAML page as well as other application sources, and will generate that resource value as the property value in the run-time objects.

Since `imageSource` value changing during runtime I had to change `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource`. But the property `Source` is not a dependency property and thus the following code will raise a runtime error:

```
SmallImageSource="{Binding Source={DynamicResource imageSource},
                   Path=Source,
                   UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}
```

For that reason I need to bind the dynamic resource directly to `SmallImageSource`, which is a dependency property:

```
SmallImageSource="{DynamicResource imageSource}"
```

This again will raise a runtime error because `imageSource` is type of `Image`. `SmallImageSource` expects the value to be type of `ImageSource`.

One might suggest now to set the data context to my dynamic resource and bind the property appropriately. If I do so, I'd kill the binding of property `IsEnabled` which has another `DataContext`.

And as far as I know, `MultiBinding` is also not a solution since this provides a mechanism to bind a property against several sources but does not provide binding different properties against different contexts and sources.

While thinking about how to get on, it came to my mind that luckily I can move the `ImageSource` rigmarole into a `IValueConverter`. In the given data context of my `RibbonMenuButton` I have a string value with the appropriate value which is actually also the source of my `ImageSource`.

Anyway, I still wondering how I would solve the problem if I hadn't the other approach, i.e. if both sources were in different data contexts. Is there anything what I am not seeing? How can I ensure not to kill the other binding by overwriting the `DataContext` and though binding against a property of a dynamic resource?

---

The `imageSource` is pretty the same as the XAML example on the [DrawingImage msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage.aspx).

```
<Image x:Key="imageSource">
  <Image.Source>
    <DrawingImage>
...
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you define the "imageSource" resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try defining "imageResource" as an `ImageSource` instead of an `Image`. This works for me.

```xml
<r:RibbonWindow
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    xmlns:pc="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <pc:ImageSource x:Key="imageSource">your_image.png</pc:ImageSource>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <r:Ribbon>
            <r:RibbonMenuButton
                IsEnabled="{Binding ForegroundIsConfigurable}"
                SmallImageSource="{DynamicResource imageSource}">
            </r:RibbonMenuButton>
        </r:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```

Also, you could set the DataContext of your RibbonMenuButton without overriding IsEnabled by using an ElementName binding as follows.

```xml
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid x:Name="root">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Image x:Key="imageSource" Source="{Binding myImageSource}"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <r:Ribbon>
            <r:RibbonMenuButton DataContext="{DynamicResource imageSource}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.ForegroundIsConfigurable}"
                SmallImageSource="{Binding Source}"/>
        </r:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```

Comment: I think the second idea could work. Will try that tomorrow. The first idea, however, will not work. I forgot to mention that I paint the image myself, there's not image to link to.

Comment: @Em1 Regarding the first idea, you could update the imageSource key of the resource dictionary on the fly if you had access to it from the code that paints your images.

Comment: I just tested the second approach. For some reason it didn't work for me with ElementName but with RelativeSource. - I paint the image in XAML, I updated the question regarding that. I didn't debug into the issue that when ImageSource is directly being used (instead of Image.Source) content cannot be added.